# Unable to move a file on a network shared drive?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, cifs

```
mv -t Perry perry.iso
mv: cannot move ‘perry.iso’ to ‘Perry/perry.iso’: Device or resource busy
```

Fuser and lsof turn up nothing accessing perry.iso - running the commands returns no output.  Perry is a directory in the directory Customers.  perry.iso also resides in Customers.  Customers is a directory on an external drive mounted through cifs.  I only want to move the .iso file into the directory.  I'm probably overlooking something real simple here, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: Do you have write permission for the target folder?  Can you copy/move other files into it?

Comment: I created the folder myself logged onto the same machine I'm on now, and I successfully moved a .log file to the Perry directory from Customers.